# Axios.js - preventDefault() not working when clicking and data parameters seems off

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, axios

So I have many problems with my current code.

First, I'm using Axios to send requests, I'm trying to get data from my Symfony back-end, however it's always sending a GET request no matter I give to the method. It's not a "problem" but having such behaviour is annoying in the way that it's not doing what it is supposed to. If I change `method` to POST, it will still send a GET request...

However the bigger problem is that the `preventDefault()` function I'm using is not working, I added an eventListener on a link tag, but everytime I click it, it displays the JSON response sent from my backend...

This is the code I have :

```html
<a id="link" href="{{ path('corrigerExercice', {'id': id}) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Corriger</a>
```

A simple  tag.

```js
document.onload = function () {
  var link = document.getElementById('link');
  link.addEventListener('click', onClickCorrection);
  console.log(link);

  function onClickCorrection(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const test = this.href;
    console.log(test);

    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: url,
      data: 'true'
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
};
```

Note that `console.log(link)` and `console.log(url)` aren't printing anything in the console (I'm using Firefox ...) I have no clue why.

Moreoever, I have a problem with back-end that seems related to the paratemers given to the request. I'm passing "true" as `data` and in my backend I'm doing this

```php
/**
 * @Route("/corrigerExercice/{id}", name="corrigerExercice")
 */
public function corrigerExercice(Exercice $exercice, Request $request): Response
{
    $test = $request->query->get('data');
    if ($test == "true") {
        $message = "Contains true";
    } else {
        $message = "Does not contain true";
    }
    $contenu = $exercice->getContenu();
    return $this->json(['code' => 200, 'message' => $message, 'contenu' => $contenu], 200);
}
```

This is the reponse I have :

```
code    200
message "Does not contain true"
```

The response is displayed directly in the browser, not in the console. So the `preventDefault()` doesn't seem to work correctly here.

I'm honestly lost and clueless about why such simple snippets of code aren't producing the expected results I want. The expected results here would be that cliking the button link would not display the request but print it in the console log, the request is sent with the data parameters, that my backend could correctly "analyze", here is just a basic Strings comparison and send the appropriate response...

Anybody could help me fix those problems please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I founded some issues on javascript side. (And i'm not specialist but it works)

- Event capture works fine on anonymous function on window.onload
- You have to send 'this' to your function onClickCorrection
- use .getAttribute('href') to get value of 'href'

Hope it will be useful

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <a id="link" href="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1" >Corriger</a>

  <script  type="text/javascript">


    window.onload = function () {

      var link = document.getElementById('link');
      link.addEventListener('click', function(){
        onClickCorrection(this);
      });
      console.log(link);

      function  onClickCorrection(element) {

        event.preventDefault();
        const href = element.getAttribute('href');
        console.log(href);

        axios({
          method: 'get',
          url: href,
          data: 'true'
        })
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      }
    };


  </script>

</body>
<html>
```